# Symmetric multilinear form from an homogenous form.

Tags: multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.
Let $\phi:V\to\mathbb{R}$ a homogeneous form of degree $n$, *i.e.* $\phi(\lambda v)=\lambda^n \phi(v)$.

If we define the symmetric multinear [**!see edit!**] operator $\Phi:V^n\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$\Phi[v_1,\ldots,v_n]=\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{1\leq j_1<\cdots<j_k\leq n} (-1)^{n-k}\phi (v_{j_1}+\cdots+v_{j_k}),$$
then we can see that for any  $v\in V$, $\Phi(v,\ldots,v)=\phi(v)$ (using homogeneity and [this combinatoric formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465172/show-this-equality-the-factorial-as-an-alternate-sum-with-binomial-coefficients)).

The question is: Is this necessarily the only symmetric multilinear form $\Phi$ satisfying $\Phi(v,\ldots,v)=\phi(v)$? 
If yes, why? 
If not, is there extra condition(s) on $\phi$ which would imply the uniqueness?

[**Edit**: It is actually not clear that with this setting $\Phi$ is multilinear. We probably need to add some condition on $\phi$.]

Comment: Where do the $v_i$'s enter on the r.h.s? Are those $s_j$'s supposed to be $v$'s?

Comment: Thanks and sorry. yes they are $v$'s. I edited it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form

The answer is almost written down in your question! You simply need to prove the identity written with $\Phi[\sum v,\sum v, \cdots, \sum v]$ instead of $\phi(\sum v)$ on the RHS must hold for any multilinear symmetric $\Phi$. This, together with the condition on the diagonal, shows this is necessarily the form of $\Phi$.

To prove this, you could take as inspiration the famous bilinear case $Q(u+v,u+v)-Q(u,u)-Q(v,v) = 2 Q(u,v)$.

Alternatively, you can prove uniqueness by deriving the expression from the above Wiki article. Consider $A=\lambda_1 v_1+\cdots+\lambda_n v_n$. Then 
$$\partial/\partial \lambda_1 \Phi[A,A,\cdots,A]\mid_{\lambda_1=0} = \cdots = n\Phi[v_1,A',A',\cdots,A']$$
and so on inductively allows you to express $\Phi$ at any point as a derivative of $\phi$. ($A'$ has no 1 term.)

Comment: Nice. I just add here the complement to understand the dots in the last equality. By multilinearity and symmetry we have:
$$\Phi[A,\ldots,A]=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \lambda_1^k\Phi[\underbrace{v_1,\ldots,v_1}_{k},\underbrace{A',\ldots,A'}_{n-k}].$$ 
But $\partial/\partial\lambda_1 (\lambda_1^k\Phi[v_1,\ldots,v_1,A',\ldots,A'])|_{\lambda_1=0}=1$ for $k=1$ and $0$ otherwise.
Hence $\partial/\partial\lambda_1 \Phi[A,\ldots,A] |_{\lambda_1=0}=n\Phi[v_1,A',\ldots,A'].$

Comment: This is an old question, but I want to say thank you for the great answer! The "alternatively" is kind of messy, actually. Directly tackling $\Phi[v_1,\ldots,v_n]=\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{1\leq j_1<\cdots<j_k\leq n} (-1)^{n-k}\Phi (\sum_{m=1}^k v_{j_m}, \dots, \sum_{m=1}^k v_{j_m})$ term-wise, on the other hand, leads to a nice and concise combinatorial proof.